# What is the most accurate (and reasonably priced) IP Geolocation database?

Tags: database, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I'm searching for an IP geolocation database.  In doing this research, I keep on happening upon corporate blather and marketing nonsense.

In your real-world experience with IP-based geolocation, what databases provide the most thorough and reliable coverage for less than $500?

Comment: Data247 has a geolocation API which costs $0.003 (1/3 penny) per query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the MaxMind database [here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location)

Comment: Ended up going with MaxMind's Webservice option - 50,000 queries for $20.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Follow-up: I've been satisfied with MaxMind.  Great service!